# How can I launch my app when a user taps on a link on another app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have a built application (Swift and iOS 9.0) and I want to post links from the app web page on social media apps such as Facebook or Twitter, is it possible to launch the app(if installed) and handle the url in my app delegate when the user taps on those links? I have read about universal links but I was wondering if there is anything else to solve it...
Thanks.

Comment: Universal links are the best approach as they will let the use launch your app if it is already installed and allow them to install it if it isn't. Using just an app URL scheme will result in nothing happening on a device that doesn't have your app

Comment: Thanks, I think I will implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It completely depends on the app.** The opening of your app from a [Universal Link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) in another app is completely up to the control of the third party app. For example, Facebook opens Universal Links in a WebView instead of the app and you have to force open your app using Facebook App links. Twitter uses a system they call App cards.

To ensure that your app opens in every case possible, you should be using [Branch](http://docs.branch.io). [This chart](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#expected-link-behavior) lays out when Branch links open the app and when they open the fallback website.

Comment: _Should be using Branch_, or you know, just read the docs and implement it. It is okay to recommend services, but universal links really aren't that complex. The Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) reference will probably be a bit more helpful too.

Comment: Agreed. They are not that complex but they do not work on Facebook (FB app links are required) and they do not work on Twitter (App Cards are required). This question explicitly asks about 2 social media apps where universal links are not supported, so just saying Universal Links is not a sufficient answer here..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use custom URL schemes in your app.

See: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) (scroll down to "Using URL Schemes to Communicate with Apps")

In summary, they say:

> A URL scheme lets you communicate with other apps through a protocol
>   that you define. To communicate with an app that implements such a
>   scheme, you must create an appropriately formatted URL and ask the
>   system to open it. To implement support for a custom scheme, you must
>   declare support for the scheme and handle incoming URLs that use the
>   scheme.

Comment: Thanks but I want to launch my app from a 'http://' url, not from a custom scheme url such as 'myapp://', so should I declare http as a custom url? Would that work? Thanks.

Comment: That will not work, and I'm not aware of any way to launch your app with an http URL. Sorry.

Comment: if you want open from a http link, then you can create a link on web e.g http://www.yoursite.com/myApp. Now when user hits the url you can redirect the user to your app's custom URL scheme.